# How do I change modal window text on click using react?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm using React, jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap. I have four panels that display titles/text. These panels also have a button that opens a modal window (Bootstrap modal) to edit the text in the panels. I can't seem to figure out how to change the title on the modal window to the corresponding panel title where the button was clicked.

I know how to do this with jQuery, but I can't figure out how to do it with React.

Here is the code I am working with

```
var questions = [
    {id: 0, title: 'one', answers: [1,2,3,4,5]},
    {id: 1, title: 'two', answers: [1,2,3,4,5]},
    {id: 2, title: 'three', answers: [1,2,3,4,5]},
    {id: 3, title: 'four', answers: [1,2,3,4,5]},
];

var EditButton = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <button className="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" data-toggle="modal" data-target="editLPSModal" onClick={ this.props.onClick } />
        );
    }
});

var SaveButton = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function() {
        console.log('close modal');

        $('#editLPSModal').modal('hide');
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={ this.handleClick }>Save</button>
        );
    }
});

var Panel = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="panel panel-info">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    { this.props.title }
                    <EditButton />
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body">{ this.props.answers }</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var LearnerPreferences = React.createClass({
    onClick: function() {
        $('#editLPSModal').modal();

    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            title: 'Modal Title'
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        var panels = questions.map(function(question) {
            return ( <Panel key={question.id} title={question.title} answers={question.answers.join(', ')} /> );
        });


        return (
            <div className="learner-preference">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    {panels}
                </div>
                <div id="editLPSModal" className="modal fade" data-backdrop="static">
                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 className="modal-title">{this.state.title}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div className="select2" data-type="ajaxTagsById">
                                        <input type="hidden"/>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <SaveButton />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    React.createElement(LearnerPreferences, {questions: questions}),
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: If all you are trying to do is update the title you just have to update the state of your component (as you have the title as a state already) using `this.setState({title: "New Title"});`

Comment: If Zane's solution doesn't work, the problem is likely with $.modal doing weird things. Consider switching from jQuery bootstrap to react-bootstrap and using the Modal component.

Comment: @ZaneM. I think that is part of what I was looking for. I also am having a problem where the event doesn't bubble up from the button to the handler. I don't know why that is.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I didn't even realize they had bootstrap for react. That looks promising, I will check that out. Thanks!